# How to split my layout on three different parts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, android-layout-weight

How to split my layout on three different parts, one to be at the top with height:wrap_content, and others (two) to be half of the screen each.

This is what I want in pictures:
I have this -> http://prntscr.com/80p964
I want this -> http://prntscr.com/80p9wz

Here's my code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".FirstFrag">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#6B6B6B">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/left_langauge_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/right_langauge_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entertexthere"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/translatedText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action" />
```

Comment: you can use a weight property of LinearLayout.

Comment: in your second linear layout set weight sum to 100 and in two child views set layout_weight to 50 eact

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts have a look at this and your images are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this is work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".FirstFrag">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#6B6B6B">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/left_langauge_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/right_langauge_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/entertexthere"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/translatedText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action" />
    </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. 
`<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".FirstFrag">`


This layout needs to be FrameLayot.. for Floating Action Button to be showed,

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use weightSum and layout_weight for that it will work as per your requirement. Please check these [Link](http://www.7solutions.in/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html) you will get it.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the Scroll view with Linear layout or Relative layout